# Passing c# string to unmanaged c++ DLL

Tags: .net, clr, unmanaged, marshalling

I have a simple application that loads an unmanaged dll and passes a few string values to it from C#. But in the C++ dll application, I receive an exception :: Tried to access a read/write protected memory. My DLL Import looks like this:

```
[DllImport("X.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl) ]
public static extern int
DumpToDBLogFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]int loggingLevel,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]int jobId,
                int threadId,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string procName,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string message);
```

and the C++ Declaration is like

```
extern "C"    
__declspec(dllexport) int DumpToDBLogFile( int loggingLevel, int jobId, int threadId, string procName, string message )
{
    //access strings..
}
```

Help please!!!

Comment: Seems code in c++ is not being able to access the heap in c#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string != LPStr
```

try:

```
extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport) int DumpToDBLogFile( int loggingLevel, int jobId, int threadId, char* procName, char* message ) { //access strings..

}
```

Comment: This is correct. Change the declaration of the function on the C++ side to accept a raw char* instead of an std::string.

Comment: I changed the declaration to char* and it worked. But should i deallocate the char* from c++ once I'm done. If i don't wouldnt that result in memory leak..??

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I have struggled with this problem for a very long time. :(

Answer (score 2):

I would modify the pinvoke signature....

```
[DllImport("X.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl) ]
public static extern int
DumpToDBLogFile(int loggingLevel, int jobId, int threadId, StringBuilder procName, StringBuilder message);
```

And from the managed side use the StringBuilder class initialized....

```
StringBuilder sbProcName = new StringBuilder(1024);
StringBuilder sbMessage = new StringBuilder(1024);
```

Then pass in the `sbProcName` and `sbMessage` to the `DumpToDBLogFile`...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.