# C# program calls vc++ function which has BSTR as input parameter

Tags: c#, visual-c++, vb6, bstr

From C# program, I am calling VC++ function which has BSTR as input parameter. I am not getting any return value. My c# application crashes.

C# : SampleCS,

**var value = object.GetValue(10, "TEST");**

VC++ : SampleCPP,

**GetValue(long index, BSTR key, double * Value)
{
  CString str = key;
  ..
  ..
}**

Any idea if I am missing anything or doing anything wrong?

Note : If I call the GetValue function of VC++ from VB6 then it works properly.

Comment: it works from VB6 because VB6 used BSTR which is different than the .NET strings.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how should I pass string value from C#, Do I need to format it before passing?

Comment: since the c++ thing appears to have been written specifically for VB6, why not change **it** to now work with .NET strings?  see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2380594/1070452

Comment: Could you post your pinvoke declaration?

Answer (score 1):

The `Marshal` class has methods for working with `BSTR`s from managed code. Try something like this:

```
// Note that the BSTR parameter in C++ becomes
// an IntPtr in this PInvoke declaration.
[DllImport("your.dll")]
private void GetValue(long index, IntPtr key, ref double value);
```

To use this method:

```
double result = 0;
var stringValue = "Foo";
var bstrValue = Marshal.StringToBSTR(stringValue);
try
{
    GetValue(0, bstrValue, ref result);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeBSTR(bstrValue);
}
```

Comment: `private void GetValue(long index, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string key, ref double value);` should also work.